# add external non-svn resource to svn

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I've a project that need very huge amount of data to run properly. The code is on svn, but these data are not. Now I've written into the REAME:

```
you need to download the data from http://... into share
for example:
  wget http://... share/...
```

I want to automatize it with svn. I want when a user does `svn co svn+ssh://...` that svn automatically download the data file. Is it possibile?

Comment: Is this for automated deployment to a test region?

Answer (score 2):

Subversion can't automatically download other files on a simple checkout.

What I normally recommend is to think of your *requirement* as a build issue. In development, you normally run some sort of build script in order to use your program. Why not make this part of the *build*?

You didn't say what the project it. However, even projects that don't have to be complied (a bunch of Python scripts, PHP code, JaveScript can go through a build phase that can help prep your checkout for testing. Do you currently have some sort of build process?

Comment: yes, I'm using an automatic building based on Makefile, probably I can configure it to download the data I need.

Comment: That's exactly what you need to do. Make a target to do the download, and maybe even make it a dependency on your build.